# Using sectionNameKeyPath with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a situation where I am using the NFC to get a list of messages. Each message has a property called "unread" which is set to true if it has not been seen. I am also using a sortDescriptor that gives me the messages in newest to oldest order.

What I am trying to do is put the messages into two sections. One for unread == true, and one for unread == false.

I set sectionNameKeyPath to @"unread" but the sections seem to be reversed. I am also unclear on what the options are for using sectionNameKeyPath. I have read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two sort descriptors, one for unread, one for your timestamp. Make sure the unread sort descriptor comes first in the sortDescriptors array.

Comment: That did it! I am seeing the messages in the unread section in both sections though. Any idea how to prevent that?

Comment: Nevermind, I had an issue in my cellForIndex method where I was using the row instead of the index path. I had it set up that way b/c previously I was using two NFCs, one for each section. All is well. Thanks for the help!